# Settings > System > Storage in Windows 10 shows incorrect values for disk usage

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, disk-space, disk-management

If I open Settings in Windows 10, then go to System > Storage, I get the following usage for C:

161Gb used of 285Gb

whereas File Explorer gives the more sensible 21Gb used of 145Gb, which is almost certainly the correct values, given that it is a 145Gb partition, and is a fresh install of Windows 10.  The C: partition is on a 480Gb SSD drive

Here is a screenshot of the partitions on my drive.

[image: partitions on my drive]

And here is a picture of the Storage screen in Settings

[image: picture of the Storage screen in Settings]

Can anyone shed some light on this mystery?

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful.  What size is your SSD/HDD?

Comment: From the few details provided, I have a feeling one is giving you partition information and the other one is giving you information for the whole drive.

Comment: I've added a screenshot and further info.